# How to manipulate Gradient Shader

Tags: node-editor, shaders, world

Being kind of new to Blender, Shaders are still kind of a mystery for me, I tried adding a Gradient Shader to the Background in World, to my surprise, I couldn't find any sliders or colors! is there a way to change the default colors in Gradient shader?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gradient texture outputs a numerical value between `0` and `1`.  You can create a color gradient from this by plugging the gradient texture into a *Color Ramp* node.

[image]

The Color Ramp takes a value between `0` and `1` (values outside this range are clamped) and outputs the color from the proper place along the set gradient.  A value of `0` will output the color on the far left, a value of `1` will output the color on the far right.

You can create a custom gradient by adding color swatches, Cycles interpolates the colors between each swatch.  Add a new color swatch by clicking the "+" button, select a swatch to change its color and position.

---

*As a technical side note, the gradient node is actually a* texture *not a shader.  A shader is a set of instructions that tell Cycles how light interacts with the surface or volume of an object, a texture is an array of colors.*

Comment: Thank you, actually Color Ramp in Blender is what I call Gradient in my terminology :) .. Any ways, so what the Gradient Texture is for? Hmm..

Comment: @Georges  You still need the gradient texture.  The gradient texture creates the black-to-white gradient (`0`-`1` really) and the color ramp is what is used to map that to a specified color gradient.